# MQTT Broker not able to receive data from Windows to Ubuntu

Tags: mqtt

I have installed mosquitto on both Ubunto and Win machine, I'm using MQTT Explorer to connect each other to check the connectivity which is working fine.

When I publish message from Ubuntu, I'm able to see it on MQTT explorer in Windows. While the reverse is not happening.

[image: MQTT explorer on windows]

Comment: You need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70302462/edit) the question to add more details about exactly what you are doing, at the moment it really is not clear if you expect messages published to the broker on ubuntu to be bridged to the broker on Windows.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.